# ERROR in : 'component selector' is not a known element: running ng-build on angular 5 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

```
  ERROR in : 'app-admin-navs' is not a known element:
```

1. If 'app-admin-navs' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-admin-navs' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]
")

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {AuthenticationModule} from './authentication/authentication.module';
import { SelectModule } from 'ng-select';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

// import {ProcessListService} from '././processflow/services/process-list.service';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SelectModule, // Select2
    NgbModule.forRoot(), // bootstrap
    AuthenticationModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,

    // lazy load other modules. they are in shared module, lazy loaded by routes


  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }





  <app-admin-navs></app-admin-navs>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

     @Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-navs',
  templateUrl: './admin-navs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-navs.component.css']
   })
```

Comment: post your app.module.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan , i have .

Comment: Include in the question the declaration of the component (including the `selector` statement in the `@Component` section), and the markup where you include the component.

Comment: @ConnorsFan i have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says you need to add the component inside the **`app.module.ts`**, I assume the name as **`AppAdminNavigationComponent`**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppAdminNavigationComponent
]
```

Comment: i have a module for that component, i have the component  declared in that module. i imported that module everywhere I used the component.

Comment: then import that module inside the app.module.ts

Comment: i am definitely sure that you are missing the module in app.module.ts

Comment: @BakareIsaacOmotayo - Is the component in the `exports` list of its module?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, i did add to the exports list

Comment: when i used 'ng build' it was suucessful, but when i use 'ng build --prod' it throws the error

Comment: i found out that i used the component in a module that did not import my shared module where my admin-navs-component resided